# key and mouse input

Tags: c++, input

i have a question:
(i use winows, visual studio)
i making a program and i need to read keyboard and mouse input istantly so like getch() (because if i use cin i need to press fullstop new line evry time).

i have this:

```
char p;

    while (running) {

        if (_kbhit()) {

            p = _getch();

            switch (p) {

            case 'w':
                mx = -1;
                map(player, mx, 0);
                break;

            case 'a':
                my = -1;
                map(player, 0, my);
                break;

            case 's':
                mx = 1;
                map(player, mx, 0);
                break;

            case 'd':
                my = 1;
                map(player, 0, my);
                break;

            case 27:
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is with `_getch()` i can't read mouse imput.

so how i can get this?

Comment: "the problem is with _getch() i **cannot** read mouse imput." ?

Comment: yep my bad cannot

Comment: C++ doesn't have any concepts of "key" or "mouse" inputs. You're using some target (OS or compiler) specific functions to read raw key input. You should really tell us what compiler and operating system you're using (even if it can be guessed). Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: What kind of "mouse input" do you expect? Selection of text on the console? The click of a mouse button? Most things you might want from a mouse mean that you are not in console land anymore.

Comment: "i need to read keyboard and mouse input istantly" So reading keyboard and mouse non-instantly is not a problem? If you demonstrate (in a [mre] ) how you use the mouse input currently, it might help users to help you. Consider separating the at least two problems you seem to be having. Ask here about reading mouse instantly, in contrast to your non-instant approach. Create a separate question on how to read keyboard instantly.